# Blackberry reduce audio player buffer

Tags: java, audio, blackberry, java-me, audio-player

I am implementing audio streaming app which handles the streaming process manually by implementing custom Datasource and Sourcestream.

From all my tests I found that the blackberry audio player has internal buffer which has to be filled before it starts playing. This causes about 2 seconds delay before the player starts.

I want to eliminate that delay and start playing as soon as possible (~300ms delay max).

Does anyone know a way to trick the player or reduce its internal buffer size?

This question is for blackberry os version >= 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the buffer size cannot be eliminated. This buffer is introduced somewhere in mid os 5 version. In previous versions you only have initial buffer you have to fill.